# Get unique values of SQL table and echo with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table with over 200 values. One of the columns on my table is 'date'. Out of all 200 values there are only 5 unique dates.

How can I list out the unique values of the dates and echo them with php. e.g. not getting back 200 instances of dates but just 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `tablename`....
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT myDate FROM myTable GROUP BY myDate
```

Or...

```
SELECT DISTINCT myDate FROM myTable
```

`DISTINCT` is a nice short hand, but if you ever then want to make use of the query for other purposes, if often constrains you a bit too much.  So I prefer the `GROUP BY` version.

Comment: I believe DISTINCT is faster than GROUP BY and a little less confusing if you don't have any aggregate functions in your query.

Comment: @ehudokai - My experience is the opposite.  Do you have anything to support `DISTINCT` having a lower cost in MySQL?  *(The 'a little less confusing' is a fair point.  But it does stop people from using distinct and then trying to get COUNTs, MINs, AVGs, etc.  To a learner, being able to get a DISTINCT but then not being able to do a count is very confusing...)*

Comment: from my research they have the same explain plan and should have similar performance, I just think DISTINCT is simpler to understand than GROUP BY for simple queries (those without aggregate functions ie: COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG).